# How do I lower aura and increase taint level thaumcraft 4.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to spread taint to an area where some is already growing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Thaumcraft but i think you just need to wait or get those tainted portals nearby.

Comment: What do you mean tainted portals?